# HTTP ERROR 404, when trying to open Swagger

Tags: kotlin, swagger

I want to open the Swagger page on Kotlin Rest Application, but it never finds the page...
This is my first time working with Kotlin, i tried to solve the problem with chat gpt, but it claims that provided code should work as expected... so what than could cause 404?

thanks in advance)

[this is the dev.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yp0U.png)
[Application config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXOPG.png)
[part of SecurityConfig class where it permits the given paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CImx7.png)

it should have opened the Swagger page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.